# while loop doesn't execute all the records from SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, swing

In my database have two tables 'customer' and 'istarak'. In the customer table have so many records and it has some records as same name. and in the istarak table have also so many records but all the records name are different.here i want to execute all the records from the istarak includes sum of total columns from all of customer's table records where customer's records name are same with the istarak record name. i try to following the bellow code. but it only one record fetching. if anyone solved me!

```
private void displayIstarakRecords(){
   try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laundry", "root", "");
    Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();

    DefaultTableModel istarakModel = (DefaultTableModel) istarakTable.getModel();

    String displayQ = "SELECT * FROM istarak";
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(displayQ);
    while(res.next()){
        String id = res.getString("id");
        String name = res.getString("name");
        String address = res.getString("address");
        String phone = res.getString("phone");
        String payment = res.getString("payment");
        String date = res.getString("date");

        String getTotalQ = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name='D-"+id+"'";
        ResultSet totRes = st.executeQuery(getTotalQ);
        Double tot = 0.000;
          while(totRes.next()){
              Double getTot = Double.parseDouble(totRes.getString("total"));
              tot = tot+getTot;
          }
        String makeTotal = String.format("%.3f", tot);

        Object[] recRows = {"D-"+id, name, phone, address, payment,makeTotal+" KD", date};
        istarakModel.addRow(recRows);

    }

   }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){}
}
```

Comment: On each iteration of the outer while loop, `tot` is initialized to 0.  Move 'Double tot = 0.000' above the outer while loop.  Or just execute a query which does the calculation in the database instead of having those loops in code.  Also, using concatenation to build a query is open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: You use the same Statement object for the two queries. When calling the `executeQuery` method the second time, the statement and the result set of the first get closed. If you use another `Statement` object for the second call your problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mexicomanni. I just changed Statement to PreparedStatement and it works magically.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS you are helpful also.

Comment: *"it works magically"* .. `catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){}` Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`